# $f(Z)=\log((1+z)/(1-z))$,$z\in \mathbb{C}$ it can expand a series of taylor

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I have to prove that $f(Z)=\log((1+z)/(1-z))$,$z\in \mathbb{C}$  it can expand a series of taylor like
$f(z)=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ( x^{2n+1})/(2n+1)$ for all $z\in D(0,1)$

my idea is to drift multiple times and find the recursion:

$f^{(1)}(z)=\frac{2(1-z)}{(1-z)^2(1+z)}$

$f^{(2)}(z)=\frac{z^2+1}{(z+1)^2(z-1)^2}$

$f^{(3)}(z)=\frac{2(-z^2+z-2)}{(1+z)^5}$

$f^{(4)}(z)=\frac{2(3z^2-6z+11)}{(1+z)^6}$

I need to find the recursion to test this but can't find generalize this.

On the other hand, Taking into account that  $\boxed{\log(1-z) = -\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}}$ and  $\log(1+z) = \sum_{n= 1}^{+\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{z^n}{n}$

but I don't get what I want using this

Comment: Hint:$$f(z)=\log{(1+z)}-\log{(1-z)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:-
Even if the above comment is sufficient (and definitely easier)you could try the euler representation of the z since its within the range of (0,1).
Then proceed to use half angle trigonometric relations such as

$1+cosx=2cos^2(x/2)$

$1-cosx=2sin^2(x/2)$

$sinx=2sinx/2.cosx/2$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). – Although, as a 2 year member of this community you should know that :)

Comment: Noted for future answers